# Java 8 How to read files faster with new API. Anomalies and optimization

Tags: java, performance, file-io, utf-8

I need to read three files less than in 3-4 seconds.

These files have UTF-16 Little Endian encoding which I can change but it's not good, because when I will download new version of those files they will have Little Endian encoding again. I have found out UTF-8 is faster to read (I work with Chinese characters).

I have found out Java 8 added lines() method, will it become faster if I use it? How to use it?
**Is there a way to optimize my code to read lines faster?**

I have 3 files to read, here are their weight and time spent on reading:

1. 72 Mb (4.4 sec)
2. 76 Mb (2.4 sec)
3. 96 Mb (0.9 sec)

Totally 8 sec.
**I can't explain why one of the files was read faster. I need this explanation too.** It's always the second or the third file.
My computer is an ultrabook with around 1 GHz speed in usual state.

My code:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.ByteOrder;
import java.nio.CharBuffer;
import java.nio.MappedByteBuffer;
import java.nio.channels.FileChannel;
import java.nio.charset.Charset;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Paths;

public class FileReader {
    private char[] chars;
    private int offset = 0;
    private int index = 0;

    public void readFile(String fileName) {
        long t1  = System.nanoTime();
        try (FileChannel fChan = (FileChannel) Files.newByteChannel(Paths.get(fileName))) {
            long fSize = fChan.size();
            MappedByteBuffer mbb = fChan.map(FileChannel.MapMode.READ_ONLY, 0, fSize);
            mbb.order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN);
            CharBuffer buffer = Charset.forName("UTF-16LE").decode(mbb);
            if (buffer.hasArray())
                chars = buffer.array();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println(e.toString());
        }
        System.out.println("readFile: " + (System.nanoTime() - t1) / 1_000_000_000.0);
    }

    public String readln() {
        while (index < chars.length && chars[index] != '\n') index++;
        String str = index < chars.length ? new String(chars, offset, chars[index] == '\r' ? index - offset : index - offset + 1) : null;
        offset = index + 2;
        index = offset;
        return str;
    }
}
```

Usage of this class:

```
public void importDictionary() {
    long t1 = System.nanoTime();
    isImported = true;
    FileReader reader = new FileReader();
    ArrayList<String[]> data = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < DICT_IMPORTS.length; i++) {
        long t2 = System.nanoTime();
        reader.readFile(DICT_IMPORTS[i]);
        for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++) reader.readln();
        String tmp = "";
        while (tmp != null) {
            String[] predata = new String[3];
            predata[0] = reader.readln();
            if (predata[0] == null || predata[0].isEmpty()) break;
            predata[1] = reader.readln();
            predata[2] = reader.readln();
            data.add(predata);
            tmp = reader.readln();
        }
        System.out.println("Read all lines: " + (System.nanoTime() - t2) / 1_000_000_000.0);
    }
    System.out.println("Importing: " + (System.nanoTime() - t1) / 1_000_000_000.0);
}
```

Help and explain me please

Benchmarking:
[image: Benchmarking my code]

First notice. This line takes a lot of time. Reading is really fast actually. I put this line before while loop. And my code started to work 3 seconds instead of 8 seconds. But it's not a good way, because now all data are similar in data arraylist. I'll try to solve this prolem myself.

```
String[] predata = new String[3];
```

But I still have an issue. Profiler in NetBeans showed this:[image]
I there any faster alternative for this line?

```
CharBuffer buffer = Charset.forName("UTF-16LE").decode(mbb);
```

Comment: "I can't explain why one of the files was read faster." - Disk cache? JVM warmup? It takes some time till everything gets compiled for full speed. Are you interested in performance just after starting the application (some desktop usage) or when running (server usage)? If the latter, then you must measure the time correspondingly.